# Valores estão sendo enviados nullos

Tags: java, android, array, rxjava

Por alguma razão os arrays estão sendo enviados nulos em setListGrades, porém dentro do log mostra os arrays normais. A API está sendo consumida corretamente, então porque está nulo no envio deste método?

```
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(GradeModel grades) {

                        BigDecimal[] gradesList = new BigDecimal[grades.getReportLists().length];
                        Integer[] faultsList = new Integer[grades.getReportLists().length];
                        String[] classesList = new String[grades.getReportLists().length];

                        for (int i = 0; i < grades.getReportLists().length; i++) {
                            gradesList[i] = grades.getReportLists()[i].getGradesList();
                            faultsList[i] = grades.getReportLists()[i].getFaultList();
                            classesList[i] = grades.getReportLists()[i].getClassList();
                        }
                        Log.i(TAG, "caralhoooooo " + Arrays.asList(classesList) + Arrays.asList(gradesList) + Arrays.asList(faultsList));
                        mainPresenter.setListGrades(gradesList, faultsList, classesList);

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Posta o código completo e o erro detalhado.

Comment: Olá, obg pelo interesse. O código completo não posso pois são mais de 30 classes e centenas ou milhares de linhas. O model é um model comum com gets and setters. Não tem problemas em outras partes do código. O único problema é que nessa linha `mainPresenter.setListGrades(gradesList, faultsList, classesList);` está sendo enviado valores nulos, sendo que no log demonstra que não são nulos. O que poderia ser?

Answer (score 1):

Talves se voce fizesse como abaixo, resolveria:

```
List<BigDecimal> gradesList = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
List<Integer> faultsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<String> classesList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < grades.getReportLists().length; i++) {
    gradesList.add(grades.getReportLists()[i].getGradesList());
    faultsList.add(grades.getReportLists()[i].getFaultList());
    classesList.add(grades.getReportLists()[i].getClassList());
 }
Log.i(TAG, "caralhoooooo " + Arrays.asList(classesList) + Arrays.asList(gradesList) + Arrays.asList(faultsList));
 mainPresenter.setListGrades(gradesList, faultsList, classesList);
```

ou possivelmente

```
mainPresenter.setListGrades(gradesList.toArray(), faultsList.toArray(), classesList.toArray());
```

se der algum problema avisa que a gente tenta resolver de outra forma

Comment: Tentei a opção 1 onde usa o List em vez de arrays e dá no mesmo. E na opção dois não dá pra converter toArray pq já são arrays.

Comment: no caso entao, voce precisa marcar breakpoints no seu codigo e ir debugando para ver onde falha, possivelmente deve ser os metodos que estão retornando vazios ou sabe Deus o que pode ser, precisa debugar para encontrar a falha

Comment: Eu fiz isso e descobri que esta linha `mainPresenter.setListGrades(gradesList, faultsList, classesList);` está enviando valores nulos em vez dos arrays. Isso que me confunde